# Beautiful Soup not finding string

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

When parsing `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel` I encounter an `H2` tag which has text, yet Beautiful Soup returns a `None` type for it:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> response = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel')
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
>>> for h in soup.find_all('h2'):
...     pprint(str(type(h)))
...     pprint(h)
...     pprint(str(type(h.string)))
...     pprint(h.string)
...     print('--')
...                     
"<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>"
<h2>Contents</h2>    
"<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>"
u'Contents'          
--                   
"<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>"
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Etymology"><span id="Etymology"></span> Etymology</span></h2>
"<type 'NoneType'>"  
None                 
--                   
"<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>"
<h2><span class="mw-headline" id="History">History</span></h2>
"<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>"
u'History'           
--
```

Note that this is not a parsing issue, Beautiful Soup parses the document just fine. Why is the second `H2` element returning a `None` type? Is it due to the leading " " (space) in the string? How can I work around this? This is with Beautiful Soup 4 on Python 2.7, Kubuntu Linux 12.10.

Comment: on the 2nd H2 there is 2 span with an empty one with the id ethymology. May be bsoup fails with this one.

Comment: I did notice that. How might I code around it?

Comment: to be able to help you I need to dig in the doc as i never use bs4 - if you're not hurry I can try.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering first the first half, what's wrong...

Quoting from the [documentation of bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string): "If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`."

And now the other half, how to fix it.

Quoting again from the same source: "If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at just the strings. Use the `.strings` generator.".  Better still, use the `.stripped_strings` generator, concatenate the results and I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: '.string'/ '.stripped_string' are not working for me. But '.contents' is working and returns a list of string I need. Can you please explain why is this?

Comment: @user2831683 Can you provide a minimal instance of your problem?  In a separate question, if it's long...

Comment: Solved it. Actually in my case bs4.element.Tag object had too many strings to refer to, so it could not decide which one string to return. So it returned 'None'. Found exact solution to my problem in another question. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I thinks this is because the second `h2` has no text, instead it has a `span` as a child (and that span has another child as its child which makes that `h2`'s grandchild.

for this kind of parsing use generator-based attributes like `.stripped_strings` and `.strings`.

```
>>> s.find_all('h2')
[<h2>Contents</h2>, <h2><span class="mw-headline" id="Etymology"><span id="Etymology"></span> Etymology</span></h2>]
>>> list(s.find_all('h2')[-1].stripped_strings)
[u'Etymology']
```

Comment: Your code works but the justification is not quite right.  If there was just one `span` (or any list of nested `span`s), it would have been OK.

Comment: @nickie you mean span (not spam;)

Comment: Actually, the second `h2` does have text, right after the `</span>`. However, it does look like it is not legal HTML.